# python web scraping csv file

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, export-to-csv

Here is my code for web scraping which to make it to get contents and export to csv file. May I know why will have spacing in every rows in csv file? Can solve it? Thanks!

Python Code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

session = requests.session()

payload = {"i0023":"XXXXXX", 
          "i0025":"XXXXXX"
         }
         
session.post("http://192.168.XXX.XXX/checkLogin.cgi",data = payload)

s = session.get("http://192.168.XXX.XXX/m_departmentid.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('div', attrs={ "class" : "ItemListComponent"})
tbody = table.find_all('tbody')

rows = []

for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text for val in row.find_all('td')[0:6]])

with open('test.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

Source code

```
<div class="ItemListComponent">
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th rowspan="3" scope="col">Department ID</th><th colspan="5" scope="col">Page Total/Page Restriction</th><th rowspan="3" scope="col"></th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="3" scope="col">Total Prints</th><th colspan="1" scope="col">Color</th><th colspan="1" scope="col">Black & White</th></tr>
<tr><th colspan="1" scope="col">Total</th><th colspan="1" scope="col">Color</th><th colspan="1" scope="col">Black & White</th><th colspan="1" scope="col">Print</th><th colspan="1" scope="col">Print</th></tr>

</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>7654321</td><td>11</td><td>0</td><td>11</td><td>0</td><td>11</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="/m_departmentid_edit.html?id=100">0000100</a></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="departmentIdDelete(100)"/><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Clear Count" onclick="departmentIdClear(100)" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="/m_departmentid_edit.html?id=101">0000101</a></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="departmentIdDelete(101)"/><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Clear Count" onclick="departmentIdClear(101)" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="/m_departmentid_edit.html?id=102">0000102</a></td><td>18</td><td>5</td><td>13</td><td>5</td><td>13</td><td><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="departmentIdDelete(102)"/><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Clear Count" onclick="departmentIdClear(102)" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="/m_departmentid_edit.html?id=103">0000103</a></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="departmentIdDelete(103)"/><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Clear Count" onclick="departmentIdClear(103)" />
</td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="/m_departmentid_edit.html?id=104">0000104</a></td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="departmentIdDelete(104)"/><input class="ButtonEnable" type="button" value="Clear Count" onclick="departmentIdClear(104)" />
</td></tr>
```

[image: Figure1][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MnKK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You opened it as "wb" which is write bytes. Open it as "w" instead.

Comment: After testing, it can export to csv file now. However, the data is not correct when I opened the csv file. As long as the header is correct. Thanks.

Comment: I would help further, but it doesn't have an example place that it pulls from, so beautiful soup doesn't return anything. But if I had to guess, it's because you're row text is reset every time it goes through the loop, so you miss all but the last loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Look forward to help me solve it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the string to convert it to bytes object.

```py
for row in soup.select(".ItemListComponent tbody tr")[1:215]:
    row_text = [x.text.encode() for x in row.find_all("td")]
    print(",".join(row_text))
```

Comment: After testing, it's still not working. The error message like that: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Thanks.

Comment: Oops, I misread it. you need to encode to convert string to byte.
I have updated the code.

Comment: Sorry for that. What that mean of this error: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, bytes found? Thanks.

Comment: Is it related to join function? Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Which line number you got this error? 

can you please send error traceback>

Comment: print(",".join(row_text)) <---- this line

Comment: change it to

print(b",".join(row_text))

Comment: Thanks. It can working again. Like that below:
b'0000101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \n'
b'0000102, 18, 5, 13, 5, 13, \n'

Comment: I have changed the code to writer.writerows(b", ".join(row_text)), but failed to export. The error message like that: _csv.Error: iterable expected, not int

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all of you. Finally, I found the solution to fix the problem which is missing to add the newline argument in csv writer.

Code

```
session = requests.session()

payload = {"i0023":"XXXXX", 
          "i0025":"XXXXX"
         }
         
session.post("http://192.168.XXX.XXX/checkLogin.cgi",data = payload)

s = session.get("http://192.168.XXX.XXX/m_departmentid.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(s.text, "html.parser")

table = soup.find('div', attrs={ "class" : "ItemListComponent"})
table_tbody = table.find('tbody')

rows = []
 
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text for val in row.find_all('td')])   


with open(("\test.csv"), 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```